# Combine concat with substr in a sql query

Tags: sql, db2

I am doing a sql query (in DB2) and I need to extract a date that is in the following form:

2022-01-01

In the Where condition I am using:

```
CONCAT(SUBSTR('$P!{FLIB}', 1, 4), SUBSTR('$P!{FLIB}', 5, 2), SUBSTR('$P!{FLIB}', 9, 2))
```

Where '$P!{FLIB}' is the date, but I get the following error:
Invalid number of arguments for CONCAT function.

It should be like 20220101

Comment: Shouldn't the middle one be SUBSTR('$P!{FLIB}', 6, 2)?

Comment: `CONCAT` only supports 2 arguments in DB2. What are you really trying to do? Why do you need to "extract a date", can't you convert it to a `date` (apparently it isn't now)?

Comment: I am using Jaspersoft, and it turns out that previously we had worked with a Bigdecimal format for dates, the initial parameter that is passed is string and then it is treated as bigdecimal, that is why I need to extract the date first so that it remains as 20210101 because it generates errors .

Comment: What I tried was to extract the first four values, then 2 and finally the remaining 2 and concatenate them, but obviously it didn't work.

Comment: I don't follow completely, but alternatively you could take the whole substring (`SUBSTR('$P!{FLIB}', 1, 10)`), and than replace the `'-'` with an empty string.

Comment: Can you tell me in the answer how it would be? If it works, I mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in a comment, a different approach is to first take the entire 'date' substring, and then replacing the '-' with empty string:

```
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTR(x, 1, 10), '-', '') 
FROM (VALUES('2022-01-01'))V(x)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=bb7c97f296cf7367d6ea364053dc1b42)